# Differentiate between field access and function call in __index

Tags: lua

If I set `__index` for the metatable of `foo` and then invoke either:

```
print(foo.x)
```

or

```
print(foo.x())
```

is there a way to differentiate between these two calls in my custom `__index` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because those aren't two different things. They're the same operation: take the table and access the field named `x`. The fact that it will attempt to call a function on the result is entirely irrelevant. After all, you could do this:

```
local temp = foo.x
temp()
```

And that should be 100% equivalent Lua code.